# Publish to multiple locations with SP2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How can I publish a blog post or news article and have it appear in multiple locations throughout my site?

For example: Can I publish a news article on a page called "news" and also have parts of it (the main text, the main image) appear on the homepage without having to do anything else?

The purpose would be for different departments to be able to publish articles and have it appear automatically on the homepage without needing to code anything.

I'm using SP2013 Online

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint you don't usually publish the content to multiple locations, but instead configure the destinations to display content from the source.

So, I'd consider creating News list on each source, and in that list there would be new field, call it e.g., "Show for other departments". Then on the front page of other departments, a Search Results Web Part is used to display all items that have "Show for other departments" checked (and some other refiners perhaps).

Instead of using search (articles will be shown only after next search crawl is done), you might consider using Content Query Web Part. But beware, it can make page loading very slow if you want to display latest articles from a lot of subsites and CQWP has to go through all subsites every time you reload the front page.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to do this with blog posts? and is it possible to edit the display of the contents? When I add a new item to the list, I'm able to add basic info and attachments but I was hoping for this to be more of a news article, not sure if that's possible?

Comment: You can edit blog content type and add the required field. Also, you can edit the page layout of the blog article to display this new field. Attachments might be possible, you need to look at the Advanced Settings on the list where your (blog) articles are on to see if you can enable attachments on that list.